# Navigation buttons missing from UIImagePickerController when added to UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

Got a strange problem. The cancel button that normally is shown at the navigation bar when you add a UIImagePickerController is missing when I add it to my UIPopoverController.

I have tried to subclass the UIImagePickerController and add a navigation button to the navigation bar myself, but it did not show up.

If I select my camera roll the back button gets automatically added, but the cancel button is still missing.

Anyone know what could cause this?

Here is the code i use. Note that _popOver is the instance of my UIPopoverController.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[_popOver setContentViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this code and now I think it's a default behavior. UIImagePickerController usually presented as modal view controller and the aim of Cancel button is to dismiss it. When you put UIImagePickerController into UIPopoverController then Cancel button became meaningless. For dismissing this you can just tap anywhere (except UIPopoverController view). If you want to access UIImagePickerController when UIPopoverController will/did dismissed use UIPopoverControllerDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = (UIImagePickerController*)popoverController.contentViewController;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You might be right, but it surely limits the design possible with this component. Dismissing the popover is not an alternative in my application, as you have to navigate in several menus inside a navigation controller before the image picker is launched. It is therefore natural that you get back to the point before you launched the picker if you cancel it. Dismissing the popover would logically bring you back to the root of the navigation controller, or possibly to the same page as you previously where before dismissing.